# "failed to execute git ls-remote --tags --head Error #1" on ember new

Tags: git, ember.js, ember-cli

I am brand new to ember and even newer to Ember-CLI. I have recently attempted to setup and begin using Ember-CLI, however, my main machine is throwing an obscure issue that I cannot find a resolution to. I have attempted to resolve the issue using resolutions from similar issues, moving the gitconfig file, validating environment variables included git, and installed python. All of this comes to the same result. An error number that does not appear specifically in any of my research.

I have successfully set this up on a secondary machine and have gotten past this step. Both machines are Windows 7 64 sitting on the same network.

I realize this has to be some sort of botched install. I have repeatedly uninstalled git, bower, ember-cli, and npm just to restart my machine and redo the installation process several times. Something appears to be stuck in the wrong place or looking in the wrong place.

Here is the specific error I am receiving.
[image: specific error]

Here is the version information on what I have installed.
[image: version information]

Looking for any type of advice I can get. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something wrong when initializing your new app's git repository.

You can create a new Ember-cli application without a git repository this way :

```
ember new <you app name> --skip-git
```

If you need your project to be a git repo, you can then create it with :

```
cd <your app name>
git init
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the command that sparks the above error is
"ember new <app name> . 
Sorry if I did not make that clear. 

I just ran git init on my containing folder then an app create as before and received the same result.